# MSBUILD doest not detect change in project files

Tags: windows, visual-studio, msbuild, msbuild-task

I need to build a C++ library and I need to use msbuild from the terminal. I followed the procedure in [Here in the learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-using-msbuild-to-create-a-visual-cpp-project?view=vs-2017) and did everything to the point and the project build was successful.

Then I changed the file name from main.h to main.hpp and also changed the name inside the project file(.vcxproj) then ran

```
msbuild /t:Clean

msbuild myproject.vcxproj /p:configuration=debug
```

it said it cannot find a file named "main.h" BUT I had changed the required file name to "main.hpp" inside the myproject.vcxproj file corresponding to the renaming of main.h to main.hpp.

why is it still looking for the old file?

Comment: Can my answer work? If not, can you share a screenshot like me here, then i can check it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This issue seems to result from that you haven't changed the main.h to
>   main.hpp in main.cpp file.

**Is the error you get similar to pics below?**

[image]
[image]
According to the error message we can find that this error comes from the CIComplie target.

And open myproject.vcxproj file, we can find this sentence `<ClCompile Include="main.cpp" />`.

Now it’s clear that this issue results from this, as you mentioned you have changed the file name and do same changes in .vcxproj file. But you haven’t do the change in main.cpp.

So when this target starts compiling, it can’t find the main.h file which defined in code like“#include "main.h"” in main.cpp.

```
Changing the “#include "main.h" to “#include "main.hpp" can help.
```

Any update or feedback you can share here.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Have a nice day!

Answer (score -1):

I think you should have cleaned before you renamed the file. It is possible some object files *.obj still pointed to the old file, or some other temporary file that visual studio had that pointed to the old file name.